# HyperJaxb - Any way to exclude xml schemas which are imported in included schemas?

Tags: hyperjaxb

Here's my problem:

I have two .xsd files, let's call them a.xsd and  b.xsd. What I want to achieve is to generate all the classes from a.xsd excluding the classes in b.xsd. Now the problem is, that a.xsd references a type in b.xsd (via a ), so even when excluded, the classes in b.xsd get build. Is there some way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't exclude a schema, but you can exclude a schema-derived package.

Please see [Ignoring packages](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Generating+ORM+metadata#GeneratingORMmetadata-Ignoringpackages):

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema-ignored.xsd" node="/xsd:schema">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.issuesignored"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    <hj:ignored-package name="org.jvnet.hyperjaxb3.ejb.tests.issuesignored"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Since you actually have a reference to a type from `b.xsd` somewhere in `a.xsd` you will need to break this reference. You can either ignore this property using `hj:ignored` or customize it with `xjc:dom` to make it a DOM element in the Java class.

ps. I'm responding to `users@hyperjaxb.java.net` faster than to questions on SO.